# Recursion in python didn't work out

Tags: python

```
def make_ship(length):
    ship = []
    ship_tmp = []
    ship_row = random_row(board, length)
    ship.append(ship_row)
    ship_col = random_col(board, length)
    ship.append(ship_col)
    i = 0
    if randint(0,1) == 0:
        while i<length:
            ship_tmp.append(ship[:])
            ship[0] += 1
            for ship in ship_tmp:
                if ship in ship_all:
                    make_ship(length)
                else:
                    ship_all.append(ship)
                    i+=1
    else:
        while i<length:
            ship_tmp.append(ship[:])
            ship[1] += 1
            for ship in ship_tmp:
                if ship in ship_all:
                    make_ship(length)
                else:
                    ship_all.append(ship)
                    i+=1
```

The aim of this problem is to generate several ship on the board and prevent them from touching each other,but the `make_ship()` recursion didn't work out, how to solve this problem?

Comment: "Didn't work out"? What happened?

Comment: when i>1, it said maximum recursion depth exceeded

Comment: grab a debugger and step through the code to see what it is doing. Try pycharm

Comment: You haven't really explained the question very well. It looks like maybe Battleship? How many ships are you trying to place? What is the format of board? For recursion to work, it must call itself on smaller versions of the problem until it reaches a version small enough to solve trivially, then combine small solutions into larger ones. If make_ship(length) just calls make_ship(length) then the problem never gets smaller or closer to a solution!

Comment: I have the same question as @HughBothwell; however, the reason behind your problem may be that "i" is always 0 when evaluated at every "make_ship" funcion is called. I guess what you wanted to do was either to use a global variable or make a class and use an attribute of the class. Anyway, I'm only guessing since functions  "random_row" and "random_col" are not described

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using gobal variable:

```
global i
i=0

def make_ship(length):
    global i
    ship = []
    ship_tmp = []
    ship_row = random_row(board, length)
    ship.append(ship_row)
    ship_col = random_col(board, length)
    ship.append(ship_col)
    if randint(0,1) == 0:
        while i<length:
            ship_tmp.append(ship[:])
            ship[0] += 1
            for ship in ship_tmp:
                if ship in ship_all:
                    make_ship(length)
                else:
                    ship_all.append(ship)
                    i+=1
    else:
        while i<length:
            ship_tmp.append(ship[:])
            ship[1] += 1
            for ship in ship_tmp:
                if ship in ship_all:
                    make_ship(length)
                else:
                    ship_all.append(ship)
                    i+=1
```

You may also try to use class to solve the problem:

```
class ship_class(object):                                                       
    def __int__(self,length):                                                   
        self.i=0                                                                
        self.length=length                                                      

    def make_ship(self):                                                        
        ship = []                                                               
        ship_tmp = []                                                           
        ship_row = random_row(board, length)
        ship.append(ship_row)
        ship_col = random_col(board, length)
        ship.append(ship_col)
        if randint(0,1) == 0:
            while self.i<self.length:
                ship_tmp.append(ship[:])
                ship[0] += 1
                for ship in ship_tmp:
                    if ship in ship_all:
                        make_ship(self.length)
                    else:
                        ship_all.append(ship)
                        self.i+=1
        else:
            while self.i<self.length:
                ship_tmp.append(ship[:])
                ship[1] += 1
                for ship in ship_tmp:
                    if ship in ship_all:
                        make_ship(self.length)
                    else:
                        ship_all.append(ship)
                        self.i+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Things you should learn:

1. Global variables are rarely a good idea; they break encapsulation and make debugging hard because you can't tell where changes came from (or *didn't* come from, sometimes!).
2. Meaningful comments are a very good thing. Meaningful variable names are even better. Well-factored, meaningful classes are a gift from heaven.
3. Keep your functions simple - ideally less than 10 or 12 lines. This lets you reason about the whole thing at once, so you can see most problems at a glance. If it's too complicated to think about the whole thing at once, maybe you should break it down further.
4. Recursion is good for dealing with branching structures. A ship is not a branching structure.

Here is a simple class-based solution:

```
import random

class Board:
    def __init__(self, width, height, empty_char="."):
        """
        Create a new gameboard
        """
        self.width  = width
        self.height = height
        self.empty_char = empty_char
        self.ships  = []

    def __str__(self):
        # make an empty board
        board = [[self.empty_char] * self.width for y in range(self.height)]
        # add ships
        for ship in self.ships:
            ship.draw(board)
        # return as string
        return "\n".join("".join(row) for row in board)

    def add_rand_ship(self, length, char, tries=10):
        """
        Add a ship at a random location on the board,
          not overlapping any existing ships
        """
        for try_ in range(tries):
            # create a random Ship
            new_ship = Ship.rand_ship(length, char, self.width, self.height)
            # make sure it doesn't intersect any existing ships
            if not any(new_ship.hits(ship) for ship in self.ships):
                self.ships.append(new_ship)
                return
        raise ValueError("Failed creating new ship after {} tries".format(tries))

class Ship:
    def __init__(self, x, y, length, char, horiz=True):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.length = length
        self.char = char
        self.horiz = horiz

        # get every square occupied by this ship
        if self.horiz:
            self.locations = set((x + dx, y) for dx in range(self.length))
        else:
            self.locations = set((x, y + dy) for dy in range(self.length))

    def draw(self, board):
        """
        Draw ship to board
        """
        for x,y in self.locations:
            board[y][x] = self.char

    def hits(self, ship):
        """
        Does this ship occupy any of the same locations as the other one?
        """
        return bool(self.locations & ship.locations)

    @classmethod
    def rand_ship(cls, length, char, board_width, board_height):
        """
        Create a new Ship at a random board location
        """
        horiz = random.choice((False, True))
        x = random.randint(0, board_width  - (length if horiz else 1))
        y = random.randint(0, board_height - (1 if horiz else length))
        return cls(x, y, length, char, horiz)

def main():
    bd = Board(30, 20)

    for length in (2, 2, 3, 4):
        for side in ("X", "O"):
            bd.add_rand_ship(length, side)

    print(bd)

main()
```

which produces something like:

```
..............................
..............................
..............................
.X............................
.X............................
.X............................
..............................
..............................
..........OOO.................
...............XX.............
..............................
...X..........................
...X......OOOO................
...X..........................
...X..........................
............OO................
..............................
..............................
...X.....................O....
...X.....................O....
```